# Even Odd Functions

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

Let $e(x)$ be an even function and let $o(x)$ be an odd function, such that
$e(x) + x^2 = o(x)$ for all $x.$ Let $f(x) = e(x) + o(x).$ Find $f(2).$

We could write $f(x)=e(x)+e(x)+x^2.$

We want to find $f(2),$ so could we write it as $f(2)=e(2)+e(2)+2^2.$ (I'm not sure if we can.)

How would I finish the problem?

Comment: $e(x)+x^2$ is an even function.  The only function that is even and odd is the $0$ function

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite fully understand what you're trying to convey.

Comment: There is only one pair of functions that satisfy the definitions of $e(x), o(x)$

Comment: How would I compute $f(2)$ using that, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e(x)$ is an even function, then so is $e(x)+x^2$,

so $e(x)+x^2=o(x)$ means $o(x)$ is an even function and an odd function,

which means that $o(x)=0$, so $e(x)=-x^2$.

Therefore, $f(2)=e(2)+o(2)=-2^2$.

Comment: OHHHHH!!! I see. I've never come to a circumstance where a function is both even and odd.

Comment: There's only one function that is even and odd:  $f(-x)=f(x)=-f(x)\implies f(x)=0$

Comment: Hmm, I've never thought of that, quite interesting. This function is called the zero function?

Comment: Yes; it could be called the identically zero function